# why are build variable values masked

Tags: tfsbuild

What cases a variable value to be masked in the output of VSTS 2017 build definitions?. I have a variable named *BuildEnvironment* that I'd like to see in the build output. An example usage shows:

> Applying transformations 'D:\TFS2017Build\Agent1_work\1\a\web.********.config'

I want to show:

> Applying transformations 'D:\TFS2017Build\Agent1_work\1\a\web.test.config'

Is this a facet of the Task I'm using in the Build Step ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you make the variable Secret:

[image]

If you make variables secret, they are automatically masked out of any log output from the build or release. Check https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#secret-variables.

To expose the variable, just don't make the variable secret.

Comment: This variable is not secret. Other variables in the same build definition are, but not this one. This value is only masked in the Apply Transformations task, not in a Build Solution or Copy Files. 
If your theory were true, wouldn't the value 'test' be masked in All Logs?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue with Apply transformations task (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jungeriusit.jungit-apply-transformations). In my build log, I can see the variable value like "Applying Transform File: C:\Windows\SERVIC~2\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\work-17904\Web.Debug.config".